# Using decorators in classes python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

Please help to understand how to correctly use decorators in classes.
For example, I want to check variables before executing the class, and if it's exist run class with this variable.
How to do this?

My not working example :

```
import os,sys
import requests


def checkCredentials(function):
  KEY = os.environ['KEY']
  if KEY:
    print("exist")
    return KEY
  else:
    print("nope")
    sys.exit(0)


@checkCredentials
class StartUp(object):

  def __init__(self, argument1):
    self.argument1 = argument1

  def printstr(self):
    print(self.argument1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  start = StartUp()
```

My error :

```
python3.6 ./main.py 
exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 26, in <module>
    start = StartUp()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: The problem is your decorator is returning a string (or `None` if the `KEY` doesn't exist. A decorator needs to return a callable object, usually a small modification (ie a "decoration") of the one passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up some more on decorators, maybe check [PEP 3129](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/) or [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). The following example from the former PEP illustrates the semantics of class decorators:

```
# Solution 1: Without class decorators
class A:
  pass
A = foo(bar(A))

# Solution 2: With class decorators
@foo
@bar
class A:
  pass
```

The two solutions produce identical results. In `Solution 1` the functions `foo` and `bar` are called explicitly to modify the initial class `A` and produce a modified variant. By using decorators, the same effect can be achieved much more clearly: this is `Solution 2`.

Let's apply this to your code example. Your final line of code is

```
start = StartUp()
```

which translates to

```
start = checkCredentials(StartUp)()
```

However, `checkCredentials` either returns nothing or a `str`, hence the `TypeError`. I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve with the decorator. If all you want is a test for the presence of the specific environment variable, the following decorator might produce the desired effect:

```
def checkCredentials(cls):
  KEY = os.environ['KEY']
  if KEY:
    print("exist")
    return cls
  else:
    print("nope")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Note that this returns the original class from the decorator iff the environment variable is set (happy code-path) and terminates execution otherwise (hence there's no need to return anything form the decorator).

Comment: Awesome answer!!! thanks a lot! just one more question. When Im doing "return cli" can I run "cli" with argument KEY?

Comment: @KostiaSkrypnyk You can. **BUT** that might not have the desired effect. A class decorator should return a new class which *afterwards* can be instantiated. If you pass a class into the decorator **and** construct and return an instance of this class from the decorator this breaks the behaviour expected from a decorator. To me it seems like you are trying to use python decorators for something else then their intended purpose.